# Change x axis variable in conditional distribution barplot in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to look at the conditional distributions of some data to compare how they look using a barplot. I would like to change the variable of the x-axis when I look at a different conditional distribution of a contingency table but R does not do so. It keeps the x axis variable and the plotted variable the same (with frequency distribution on the y axis).
Here is my code:

```
eyecolour<-matrix(c(43, 62, 48, 27,35, 26, 30, 29,27,39,61,33), ncol=4, byrow=T)
colnames(eyecolour)<-c("Blue", "Brown", "Green", "Other")
rownames(eyecolour)<-c("Glasgow", "Sheffield", "London")

barplot(prop.table(eyecolour, 1), legend=T, beside=T)
barplot(prop.table(eyecolour, 2), legend=T, beside=T)
```

I was expecting the two barplots to show Cities on the x axis for one plot and eye colours on the x axis for the other. I wasn't sure which - I'm just learning.
Can anyone help me to produce that result?

Comment: If you want the first one to show cities maybe `barplot(t(prop.table(eyecolour,1)))`?

Comment: Yes, that's what I was looking for, thanks. I also wanted to have the bars for the individual eye colours next to each other, rather than in a single stack, but now it won't let me use the beside= and legend= arguments, saying that they are unused. Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks for you help, I've sorted it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your first question you can simply use `t()` so that it now plots the cities rather than the `eyecolour`s. You might notice that the two outputs of your `prop.tables` have the same structure (`eyecolour` in the columns). They just have different numbers depending on the margin you specify. Reading the documentation for `?barplot` it says that:

> If height is a matrix and beside is FALSE then each bar of the plot corresponds to a column of height, with the values in the column giving the heights of stacked sub-bars making up the bar. If height is a matrix and beside is TRUE, then the values in each column are juxtaposed rather than stacked.

This suggests that `barplot` uses the columns as the heights in the plot which is why you need to transpose your matrix so that the columns are `cities` instead of `eyecolour`s.

Something like:

```
barplot(t(prop.table(eyecolour, 1)), legend=T, beside=T)
```

[image]

Comment: That's absolutely perfect, thank you. I'd managed to get a comma in the wrong place when adding the other arguments.